# How do I pipe commands inside for loop in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script to iterate through file lines with given value.

The command I am using to list the possible values is:

```
cat file.csv | cut -d';' -f2 | sort | uniq | head
```

When I use it in for loop like this it stops working:

```
for i in $( cat file.csv | cut -d';' -f2 | sort | uniq | head )
do
    //do something else with these lines
done
```

How can I use piped commands in for loop?

Comment: It is a working to an extent, but neither sort, nor uniq does if I use them in this loop (I get the lines chopped like usual, but not sorted and grouped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk command to get sum of 3rd column for each unique value of 2nd columns:

```
awk -F ';' '{sums[$2]+=$3} END{for (i in sums) print i ":", sums[i]}' file.csv
```

**Input data:**

```
asd;foo;0
asd;foo;2 
asd;bar;1 
asd;foo;4
```

**Output:**

```
foo: 6 
bar: 1
```

Comment: I need to use other columns of the lines found by this later, so I need the data chopping first. The echo command is there to see if it works, but sadly no.

Comment: I have a table like:

asd;foo;0
asd;foo;2
asd;bar;1
asd;foo;4

I have to add all the numbers for every uniqe expression in column 2

In this example the output would be: foo: 6, bar: 1

Comment: How can I call awk for every possible unique expression?

Comment: It can be done but you need to show sample input and expected output in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88545/discussion-between-xanyi-and-anubhava).